# object Object at handleError graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I am creating a react app using amplify and graphql

my graphql schema is

```
 type Note @model @auth(rules: [ { allow: public } ] ){
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  image: String
  noteBook: NoteBook!
}

type NoteBook @model @auth(rules: [ { allow: public } ] ){
  id: ID! 
  name: String! 
  notes: [Note!] 
}
```

I have three buttons and these are their associated functions,
Create Notebook

```
async function handleCreateNoteBook(){
const data = {
  name: 'my 1st notebook'
}
await API.graphql({
  query: createNoteBook,
  variables: {input: data}
})
```

}

Create Note

```
 async function handleCreateNote(){
    const data = {
      name: 'test',
      description: 'this is a test note',
      noteBook: 'my 2nd notebook'
    }
    await API.graphql({
      query: createNoteMutation,
      variables: {input: data}
    })

  }
```

Show Notes

```
async function handleShow(){
    const noteBookData = await API.graphql({query: listNoteBooks})
    const notesData = await API.graphql({query: listNotes})
    console.log(noteBookData)
  }
```

However,
while creating a new note,
I am getting the following error

```
[object Object]
at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80145:58)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80168:7
```

I am new to graphql. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: that `[object Object]` means, you are trying to perform an operation on that `object Object` without converting that to the expected data type!

Try doing `JSON.parse(noteBookData)`.

Comment: The error is being thrown in `handleError` not `handleShow`. Please include your `handleError` code. If you're doing a `console.error(error)` you might want to switch that to `console.error(error.message)`